# CodeMagic Error, can't publish to google play store

Tags: dart, google-play, cicd, codemagic

I add google play to codemagic workflow. Android apk worked fine till build stage but after generated artifacts it shows errors in publishing stage

Publishing failed :|
Google Play failed to upload artefacts. Package not found: com.example.first.: {
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Package not found: com.example.first.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 9):

Before any API uploads to Google Play (which Codemagic relies on), there has to be a manual upload of the artifact first. Any further artifacts can be uploaded automatically with the API/Codemagic.

Though I would check over the bundle ID before I'd make the commitment.